# Process Name in 8.3 Format

Tags: windows, process, command

There is an external application which we get from our external suppliers, lets say the executable is a file named "SomeApplication.exe".

In a past version of this application, when it was started and I was looking in Taskmanager->Processes, I saw it appearing in 8.3 format with the name "SOMEAP~1.EXE".

Now we got a newer version, and in this one, in Taskmanager it is displayed normally as "SomeApplication.exe", exactly like the file name and as I would expect it.

To make it clear again: Same filename, one time process name appears in long format, one time on 8.3.

Can someone explain this behavior to me? Is it somehow controllable from implementation-side or OS-side how the process name appears?

PS: OS is always Windows Server 2008 R2 64Bit.

Comment: How is the process started?  In my experience task manager shows the path of a process as it was invoked by its parent.

Comment: It seems very independent of how the process was started. Starting it from a cmd, from within another application or from a explorer by double-clicking the exe does not make any difference.

Comment: No, I mean the path used to invoke it.  CreateProcess("SomeApplication.exe") vs CreateProcess("SOMEAP~1.EXE").

Comment: This is probably determined by one or more of the flags in the executable.  For example, there may be a flag indicating whether or not the process is long-name aware.  Or perhaps the original version is a 16-bit executable and the new one is 32-bit.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I checked with CFF-Explorer but did not find any related flag. Executable is always 32-Bit.

Comment: You could try Process Monitor see if it gives you any clue.  For example, the executable might be explicitly relaunching itself in the old version.

Comment: I have the same problem. One exe file starts a process with 8.3 name, but only in one environment, on other machines the same file starts with normal name

Comment: Same.  What gives?

Comment: Did someone find the root cause of this issue?